# Using an Android phone to pass through a dial-up modem signal

Tags: gsm, samsung-galaxy-a5

I have a Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016) and an old laptop with a built-in dial up modem.

I would like to know if there is any way to connect the modem to my mobile and use it to pass through the modem signal (as if it was just connected to a normal wall socket). I assume there would have to be some sort of special cable, but I've done some googling and there only seems to be suggestions on how to turn the phone into a modem itself instead of just passing through a signal. Is there any way that this is possible?

Comment: How do you mean to pass signal? To pass signal from what to what?

Comment: we mean to pass audio from a headphone jack to a modem port and from a phone to a modem